# c# execute large SQL statement

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

I have a large SQL statement that I'd like to run in c#, however, all the examples I've seen are for SQL statements that are one line in length.

Here's my C# code so far. After my code, I've included the Query, I'd like to run.

---

**C# Query Code**

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection conn = new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection();
           conn.ConnectionString = "Driver={Oracle in OraClient11g_home1};" +
                                   "Dbq=" + "database" +
                                   ";Uid=" + "admin" + ";Pwd=" + "admin" + ";";
           try
           {
               conn.Open();
               OdbcCommand com = new OdbcCommand("select count(*) from user_tables;", conn);
               com.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
               OdbcDataReader rdr = com.ExecuteReader();
               while (rdr.Read())
               {
                   var mystring = rdr.GetString(0);
                   MessageBox.Show(mystring);
               }                
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); 
           }
           conn.Close();
        }
```

---

**Query to Run**

```
SELECT user_id,
         user_name,
         user_name_full,
         (SELECT user_name
            FROM MD_SITE_USER
           WHERE user_id = u.GROUP_ID)
            assigned_user_group,
         user_or_group,
         CASE
            WHEN (SELECT o.grant_or_revoke
                    FROM MD_SITE_APP_ACTION a, MD_SITE_APP_ACTION_OWNER o
                   WHERE     a.action_id = o.action_id
                         AND a.action_name = 'Admin.start'
                         AND o.user_id = u.GROUP_ID) = '+'
            THEN
               'Y'
            ELSE
               'N'
         END
            "Assigned By Group?",
         CASE
            WHEN (SELECT o.grant_or_revoke
                    FROM MD_SITE_APP_ACTION a, MD_SITE_APP_ACTION_OWNER o
                   WHERE     a.action_id = o.action_id
                         AND a.action_name = 'Admin.start'
                         AND o.user_id = u.user_id) = '+'
            THEN
               'Y'
            ELSE
               'N'
         END
            "Assigned By User?"
    FROM MD_SITE_USER u
   WHERE     user_name IS NOT NULL
         AND (   CASE
                    WHEN (SELECT o.grant_or_revoke
                            FROM MD_SITE_APP_ACTION a,
                                 MD_SITE_APP_ACTION_OWNER o
                           WHERE     a.action_id = o.action_id
                                 AND a.action_name = 'Admin.start'
                                 AND o.user_id = u.GROUP_ID) = '+'
                    THEN
                       'Y'
                    ELSE
                       'N'
                 END = 'Y'
              OR CASE
                    WHEN (SELECT o.grant_or_revoke
                            FROM MD_SITE_APP_ACTION a,
                                 MD_SITE_APP_ACTION_OWNER o
                           WHERE     a.action_id = o.action_id
                                 AND a.action_name = 'Admin.start'
                                 AND o.user_id = u.user_id) = '+'
                    THEN
                       'Y'
                    ELSE
                       'N'
                 END = 'Y')
ORDER BY user_or_group, user_name;
```

Comment: Make it one line, or use StringBuilder

Comment: Are you asking how to run such long code?  You can create that in a procedure and execute the procedure.

Comment: Make it a stored procedure. Why the need to run all this inline sql code, it looks horrible!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do this... Or use StringBuilder class...

```
    new OdbcCommand(@"SELECT user_id,
         user_name,
         user_name_full,
         (SELECT user_name
            FROM MD_SITE_USER
           WHERE user_id = u.GROUP_ID)
            assigned_user_group,
         user_or_group,
         CASE
            WHEN (SELECT o.grant_or_revoke
                    FROM MD_SITE_APP_ACTION a, MD_SITE_APP_ACTION_OWNER o
                   WHERE     a.action_id = o.action_id
                         AND a.action_name = 'Admin.start'
                         AND o.user_id = u.GROUP_ID) = '+'
            THEN
               'Y'
            ELSE
               'N'
         END
            'Assigned By Group?',
         CASE
            WHEN (SELECT o.grant_or_revoke
                    FROM MD_SITE_APP_ACTION a, MD_SITE_APP_ACTION_OWNER o
                   WHERE     a.action_id = o.action_id
                         AND a.action_name = 'Admin.start'
                         AND o.user_id = u.user_id) = '+'
            THEN
               'Y'
            ELSE
               'N'
         END
            'Assigned By User?'
    FROM MD_SITE_USER u
   WHERE     user_name IS NOT NULL
         AND (   CASE
                    WHEN (SELECT o.grant_or_revoke
                            FROM MD_SITE_APP_ACTION a,
                                 MD_SITE_APP_ACTION_OWNER o
                           WHERE     a.action_id = o.action_id
                                 AND a.action_name = 'Admin.start'
                                 AND o.user_id = u.GROUP_ID) = '+'
                    THEN
                       'Y'
                    ELSE
                       'N'
                 END = 'Y'
              OR CASE
                    WHEN (SELECT o.grant_or_revoke
                            FROM MD_SITE_APP_ACTION a,
                                 MD_SITE_APP_ACTION_OWNER o
                           WHERE     a.action_id = o.action_id
                                 AND a.action_name = 'Admin.start'
                                 AND o.user_id = u.user_id) = '+'
                    THEN
                       'Y'
                    ELSE
                       'N'
                 END = 'Y')
ORDER BY user_or_group, user_name;", conn);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use a `string literal` using the `@` sign:

```
string longstring = @"SELECT
        *
    FROM MyTable
  ";
```

Note that in your case you have `"` in your query. To escape those, replace them with `""`.

```
string myQuery = @"SELECT user_id,
     user_name,
     user_name_full,
     (SELECT user_name
        FROM MD_SITE_USER
       WHERE user_id = u.GROUP_ID)
        assigned_user_group,
     user_or_group,
     CASE
        WHEN (SELECT o.grant_or_revoke
                FROM MD_SITE_APP_ACTION a, MD_SITE_APP_ACTION_OWNER o
               WHERE     a.action_id = o.action_id
                     AND a.action_name = 'Admin.start'
                     AND o.user_id = u.GROUP_ID) = '+'
        THEN
           'Y'
        ELSE
           'N'
     END
        ""Assigned By Group?"",
     CASE
        WHEN (SELECT o.grant_or_revoke
                FROM MD_SITE_APP_ACTION a, MD_SITE_APP_ACTION_OWNER o
               WHERE     a.action_id = o.action_id
                     AND a.action_name = 'Admin.start'
                     AND o.user_id = u.user_id) = '+'
        THEN
           'Y'
        ELSE
           'N'
     END
        ""Assigned By User?""
FROM MD_SITE_USER u
WHERE     user_name IS NOT NULL
     AND (   CASE
                WHEN (SELECT o.grant_or_revoke
                        FROM MD_SITE_APP_ACTION a,
                             MD_SITE_APP_ACTION_OWNER o
                       WHERE     a.action_id = o.action_id
                             AND a.action_name = 'Admin.start'
                             AND o.user_id = u.GROUP_ID) = '+'
                THEN
                   'Y'
                ELSE
                   'N'
             END = 'Y'
          OR CASE
                WHEN (SELECT o.grant_or_revoke
                        FROM MD_SITE_APP_ACTION a,
                             MD_SITE_APP_ACTION_OWNER o
                       WHERE     a.action_id = o.action_id
                             AND a.action_name = 'Admin.start'
                             AND o.user_id = u.user_id) = '+'
                THEN
                   'Y'
                ELSE
                   'N'
             END = 'Y')
 ORDER BY user_or_group, user_name;
";
```

Comment: Any reason, something like this wouldn't work?

Comment: I tried reading the SQL in from a file, but it errors out, (syntax). I know I'm missing something easy. I did cut and paste it into my code and it works that way, but I'd like to be able to read the SQL from a file. Store Procedures aren't allowed.

Comment: If you read it from a file you don't need to escape the quotes (if you did that)

Comment: The only difference from the read from file vs including it as a string is the escape for the quotes and I didn't start it with @ sign.

Comment: according to my messagebox.show as the lines are being read in with streamreader, chars are being added. Not sure why that's happening.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `chars are being added`. What type of file is this? What encoding was the file saved as?